# Address Sanitizer with gcc fails on Ubuntu 17.10 docker container

Tags: docker, gcc, address-sanitizer, ubuntu-17.10

Executing a binary compiled with `gcc 7.2.0`+`ASan` fails on Ubuntu 17.10 docker container with following error:

```
==5==HINT: LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)
```

Answer (score 7):

LSan (that performs leak checks) attaches to the program under test via `ptrace`. It fails to do so under docker as it does not have permissions. 
This can be fixed by running docker container with privileges using either of the two options:

```
docker run ....   --privileged
```

or more specific:

```
docker run ....   --cap-add SYS_PTRACE
```

`--cap-add SYS_PTRACE` is a much more preferred option for CI and automation as it restricts privileges to `ptrace` only.

Comment: How to pass the ASAN flags required for generating core to the docker environment?